# Библиотека в Jar с помощью Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar, media-library

Использую Eclipse IDE в связке с Gradle. Споткнулся об проблему с упаковкой в Runnable Jar подключенной к проекту библиотеки - она не появляется в jar'нике.
Для его получения использую команду 'build'.

При получении Runnable Jar через штатные средства среды (Ant) все классы из библиотеки появляются в папке 'com' и jar запускается. Но кроме них, появляется много лишнего мусора, который ни на что не влияет, зато много весит. Да и Gradle бросать не хочу.
Через Gradle - ни классов, ни, соответственно, запускающегося jar не получается.

*Мой build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'


mainClassName = 'formatter.MainView'
jar {
    baseName = 'PostMaker '
    version =  ' v2.0 Alpha'
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
    manifest.attributes("Class-Path": '.');
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile 'com.mpatric:mp3agic:0.8.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение (правда классы распакованы в папку, я хотел именно в jar архивах, не критично):

```
jar {
    baseName = 'name'
    version =  'version'

     // Keep jar clean:
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                   //Заполняем classpath в манифесте
                   'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }

    //Добавление class-файлов библиотек в runnable jar
     from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё заюзать плагины: [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar), [gradle-capsule-plugin](https://github.com/danthegoodman/gradle-capsule-plugin)

Взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639536/how-to-export-a-executable-jar-in-gradle-and-this-jar-can-run-as-it-include-ref) и [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle).

А то, что ты делаешь, попробуй сделать с меньшим кодом так:

```
jar {
...
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
...
}
```

Правда, в [комментариях](http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.ru/2011/11/how-to-create-jar-with-dependencies-in.html) пишу, что могут быть проблемы, если слишком много файлов будет.